# Fastest way to create similar activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity, listactivity

I have an app that contains two `ListActivity` and `ScrollActivity`. I need to create an elevated number of `ListActivity` and `ScrollActivity`. Is there a way to create those activities without having to do it manually?

Comment: You could always create a script that does that for you.  If you are on a windows box you can make clever use of sed, and awk on Cygwin to generate a lot of your files.

Comment: You can go to create - new activity - gallery and chose a default from there "scroll activity", or if you already have your code, just extend a class from it to reuse most of the usability, still you have to recreate the XML layout or use the same.

Comment: Depending on the amount of `Activities` you want it's probably faster just to use the wizard or copy-paste the classes, XML and the `<activity>` nodes in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, than actually writing a script or writing this question for that matter. Automating everything isn't always the way to go ;-)

Comment: @IsaacUrbina The xml layout is the same. Only the string change

Comment: If the string is the only thing changing, simply restart the same activity with new data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android